# Trying to upload a file to a JAX-RS (jersey) server

Tags: java, file-upload, jersey, client, jax-rs

I'm trying to upload a file and other form data using multipart/form-data client with Jersey.  I'm uploading to a REST web service also using Jersey.  Here is the server code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String create(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInfo,
        @FormDataParam("name") String name,
        @FormDataParam("description") String description) {
    Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();
    ingredient.setName(name);
    ingredient.setDescription(description);
    ingredient.setImageName(fileInfo.getFileName());
    ingredient.setImagePath(context.getRealPath("/resources/uploads/"));
    // TODO save the file.
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            ingredientService.create(ingredient);
        } catch (final InvalidParameterException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, ex.getMessage());
            json.put("result", false);
            json.put("error", ex.getMessage());
            return json.toString();
        } catch (final GoodDrinksException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
            json.put("result", false);
            json.put("error", ex.getMessage());
            return json.toString();
        }
        json.put("ingredient", JsonUtil.ingredientToJSON(ingredient));
        return json.put("result", true).toString();
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return "{\"result\",false}";
    }
}
```

I've tested the server code using a basic html form on my desktop and it works fine.  The problem seems to be in the client.  Here is the relevant client code.

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
client = Client.create(config);
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/webapp/resources").path("ingredient");
FormDataMultiPart fdmp = new FormDataMultiPart();
if (file != null) {
    fdmp.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
}
fdmp.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("name", ingredient.getName()));
fdmp.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("description", ingredient.getDescription()));

ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, fdmp);
String string = response.getEntity(String.class);
logger.log(Level.INFO, "response: {0}", string);
```

I'm getting a 400 response from the server "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

Here is the message that is spit out of the logger, this one is without a file to keep the output brief:

```
1 > POST http://localhost:8080/webapp/resources/ingredient  
1 > Content-Type: multipart/form-data  
1 >   
--Boundary_5_1545082086_1303666703655  
Content-Type: text/plain  
Content-Disposition: form-data;name="name"  
Adam  
--Boundary_5_1545082086_1303666703655  
Content-Type: text/plain  
Content-Disposition: form-data;name="description"  
Test  
--Boundary_5_1545082086_1303666703655--
```

What am I doing wrong in the client to get this working correctly?

Comment: Sample: http://puspendu.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/restful-webservice-file-upload-with-jersey/

Comment: which option did you set to show request body, I have enabled `ServerProperties.TRACING = ALL` and `ServerProperties.TRACING_THRESHOLD = VERBOSE`. But it doesn't show request body

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to add Strings to the `FormDataMultiPart` just use the `.field("name", "value")` method the same way it is used for the file attachment (queryParam does not work).

Below is a working sample:

First, the server part which returns the content of the read file as a String:

```
@Path("file")
public class FileResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response handleUpload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream stream) throws Exception {
        return Response.ok(IOUtils.toString(stream)).build();
    }
}
```

Second, the client method posting the file:

```
public void upload(String url, String fileName) {
    InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    FormDataMultiPart part = new FormDataMultiPart().field("file", stream, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);

    WebResource resource = Client.create().resource(url);
    String response = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(String.class, part);
    assertEquals("Hello, World", response);
}
```

Third, the test environment:

```
Server server;

@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    server = new Server(8080);
    server.addHandler(new WebAppContext(WEB_INF_DIRECTORY, "/"));
    server.start(); 
}

@After
public void after() throws Exception {
    server.stop();
}

@Test
public void upload() {
    upload("http://localhost:8080/file", "file.txt");
}
```

Finally, the maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The `file.txt` is at the root of the classpath and contains `Hello, World`.

Comment: Query params are really used for get operations not form opts.  The problem ended up being a bug in Netbeans 6.9.1.  They are not including a required jar.  The only work around is to upgrade the Netbeans 7.

Comment: I don't see how Netbeans can be a part of the problem. See my updated response.

Comment: I wasn't using maven to manage the libraries and netbeans when adding the jax-rs libraries was missing the mimepull.jar.  You can find multiple ticket numbers related to this issue in the Netbeans bugzilla.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected: `@FormDataParam("file") InputStream stream` also contains the boundaries and empty lines around the file data!

Answer (score 3):

Yves solution didn't work for me on the client side.
I looked around a bit and found:

- http://puspendu.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/restful-webservice-file-upload-with-jersey/
- http://neopatel.blogspot.de/2011/04/jersey-posting-multipart-data.html
- http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

non of which would work with my current jersey 1.18 (see pom extract below).
Most trouble was on the client side. I would get error messages like:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing body part entity of type 'text/plain'
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
```

The server side worked quickly with this code (which doesn't do anything interesting with
the uploaded InputStream yet - fit to your needs )

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("content") final InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
    String uploadContent=IOUtils.toString(uploadedInputStream);
    return Response.ok(uploadContent).build();
}
```

the client side would work with this code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;   
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
/**
 * upload the given file
 * 
 * inspired by
 * http://neopatel.blogspot.de/2011/04/jersey-posting-multipart-data.html
 * 
 * @param url
 * @param uploadFile
 * @return the result
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String upload(String url, File uploadFile) throws IOException {
    WebResource resource = Client.create().resource(url);
    FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
    form.field("fileName", uploadFile.getName());
    FormDataBodyPart fdp = new FormDataBodyPart("content",
            new FileInputStream(uploadFile),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    form.bodyPart(fdp);
    String response = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(String.class, form);
    return response;
}
```

pom.xml extract:

```
<properties>
  <jersey.version>1.18</jersey.version>
</properties>
```

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!--  Multipart support -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public DssResponse callPut(String url, Map<String, String> headers, FileDataBodyPart[] filePath, String boundary, String[] jsonString) throws IOException {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);
    Builder builder = webTarget.request(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    for (int i = 0; i < filePath.length; i++) {

        if (!filePath[i].getFileEntity().exists()) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid Input File - " + filePath[i].getFileEntity().getAbsolutePath());
        }

        multiPart.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart(filePath[i].getName(), filePath[i].getFileEntity()));
    }

    if (boundary != null)
        multiPart.type(Boundary.addBoundary(new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", Collections.singletonMap(Boundary.BOUNDARY_PARAMETER, boundary))));
    for (String jstr : jsonString) {
        multiPart.field("Content-Type", jstr, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    }
    if (headers != null) {
        for (Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
            builder.header(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
            System.out.println(header.getKey() + "===============>>" + header.getValue());
        }
    }

    Response response = builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));

    multiPart.close();

    // Assert.assertNotNull(response);
    if (response == null )
        throw new IOException ("Response is NULL");

    int status = response.getStatus();

    return dssResponse;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Or just write a new file and upload it:

```
Writer output = null;
    File file = null;
    try {
      String text = "Rajesh Kumar";
      file = new File("write.txt");
      output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(text);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException e");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException e");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException e");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FormDataMultiPart part = new FormDataMultiPart().field("file", is, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
    res = service.path("rest").path("tenant").path(tenant1.getTenantId()).path("file").type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, part);
```