# Severe error for using "multipart/form-data" for a file upload service - Apache Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Resource methods utilizing @FormParam and consuming "multipart/form-data" are no longer supported. See @FormDataParam
```

When a client web access is done for a Apache Jersey based Rest web service I am working right now:

```
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String uploadFile(@FormParam("file") File file, @FormParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    String fileLocation = "/files/" + fileDetail.getFileName();
    System.out.println("File location: " + fileLocation);
    // Load image
    try {
        byte[] imageBytes = loadImage(fileLocation);
        MongoConnection conn = MongoUtil.getConnection();
        conn.connect("m1", "avatar"); 
        GridFS fs = new GridFS(conn.getDB());
        GridFSInputFile in = fs.createFile(imageBytes);
        in.save();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "1";
}
```

I have tried changing from `@FormParam` to `@FormDataParam` but it's unresolved.

What could be the fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to download and use jersey-multipart.jar

Comment: Downvoted this, since if he can compile he already has the jersey-multipart dependency. The provided log-message is a message during deploy.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Path("upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@POST
public void handleUpload(@FormParam("file") InputStream file) throws Exception {
// do your thing
}
```

You can also refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772225/trying-to-upload-a-file-to-a-jax-rs-jersey-server).

For Client Side:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;

public class UploadExample {
  public void upload(String url, File f, String formName) {
    FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart().field(formName, f, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
    WebResource webResource = Client.create().resource(url);
    webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
               .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
               .post(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the counterpart client side upload form code for this? 
Will this work:
 <form action="rest/file/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
 <input type="file" name="attachmentFile" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />

Comment: The action should be /rest/upload if you have used /rest for all the rest request.