# REST services - testing PUT methods in the browser

Tags: web-services, rest, put, form-parameter

I've developed REST services. I can test the GET methods by the browser, or by a Client Application. But those who have PUT methods I don't know how to consume them by the browser...

For example, I have this method that turns a lamp on, after I insert the userId:

```
@PUT
@Path("/lampon")
@Produces({"application/json", "text/plain"})
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public boolean turnOnLamp(@FormParam("userId") String userId) throws Exception
{
    boolean response = new LampManager().turnOnLamp(userId);
    return response;
}
```

In my client application I do this, and it works:

```
    String webPage = "http://localhost:8080/BliveServices/webresources/services.actuators/lampon";

    URL urlToRequest = new URL(webPage);

    //Authentication

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", "2"));

    (...)
```

**But how can I send the userId by the browser?**

Another thing, I get this message when I build my project:

```
SEVERE: Resource methods utilizing @FormParam and consuming "multipart/form-data" are no longer supported. See @FormDataParam.
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to use one of the following: RESTClient or Poster they both plugin to firefox browser or download free version of SoapUi. They all great for testing web service and simple to use.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to test the REST-Webservice with your Browser you must install an plugin.

If you use Google Chrome you can install REST Console  I also use these plugin to test my Webservice.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn

For Firefox install these REST-Client

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/

REST CLient is also available for Safari
http://restclient.net/

For Opera you can check out the Simple REST-Client

https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/simple-rest-client/

#### For your second Question

please try as Consumes value 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: The REST-Client seems really nice. I'll try now use the 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: But I continue using the `@FormParam`? Because the error is still appearing.

Comment: @PUT
@Path("/lampon")
@Produces({"application/json", "text/plain"})
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public boolean turnOnLamp(@FormParam("userId") String userId) throws Exception
{
    boolean response = new LampManager().turnOnLamp(userId);
    return response;
}  should work...

Comment: Yes, that was I did, but I keep receiving `Resource methods utilizing @FormParam and consuming "multipart/form-data" are no longer supported. See @FormDataParam.`... I change it in every method where I use @FormParam.

Comment: are you also use 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' with your client?

Comment: yes, and I can test the PUT methods with the REST console in both ways. But it strange that the error still appears if I don't use @FormParam with multipart/form-data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658251/severe-error-for-using-multipart-form-data-for-a-file-upload-service-apache there is the same probleme ß The answer is: You will have to download and use jersey-multipart.jar

Answer (score 3):

To issue a put-request from a browser you could use jQuery's `jQuery.ajax()`. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test-url",
  type: "PUT",
  data: {userid: 1}
})
```

Would send a put-request to test-url with the specified data.