# Jersey No MessageBodyWriter for body part of type 'java.io.File'

Tags: java, image, file-upload, jersey, multipartform-data

I'm receiving that error while trying to upload a file. I have a code below and I'm receiving `No MessageBodyWriter for body part of type 'java.io. File' and media type 'application/octet-stream'` exception. I was trying to solve this yesterday whole day without success.

```
File file = new File(path);

    ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
    cc.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
    Client client = Client.create(cc);

    WebResource webResource = client.resource(Constants.URL).path("images")
            .path("create");; 
    FormDataMultiPart fdmp = new FormDataMultiPart(); 

    fdmp.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("filename", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
    fdmp.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("data", imageData));

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, fdmp);
```

I've tried some other versions but I'm constantly receiving that exception. Any advice? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to upload a file to a JAX-RS (jersey) server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772225/trying-to-upload-a-file-to-a-jax-rs-jersey-server)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(cc);
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://sample.com/uploadpath");
FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
File file = new File("c:/temp/file.txt");
form.field("filename", file.getName());
form.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));

ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class, form);
```

Comment: Thank you but also no success. Message body writer for Java type and MIME media type was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution!! I had that issue on android

simply add the following code:

import com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider;
import com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider;
.............

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getClasses().add(StringProvider.class);///////// here is the magic :)
cc.getClasses().add(InputStreamProvider.class);////
cc.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);////////

WebResource webResource = Client.create(cc).resource("www......");

FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
multiPart.field("bla", "bla bla", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

ClientResponse response = webResource.
            type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).
            post(ClientResponse.class,multiPart);
```